# how to connect an Express JS server with Angular 6 file?

Tags: angular, express

i searched about this topic but i didn't find a direct answer to make it, i am just learning about how to make a user login system using Express and and Node JS and Angular, and i need to add some pages with angular, can anyone explain to me how to do that and what modules should i use?
here is my Express JS code

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var LocalStrategu = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var jade = require('jade');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Handel sessions
app.use(session({
        secret: 'secret',
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true
        }));

//Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
    erorrFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
        var namespace = param.split('.');
        var root = namespace.shift();
        var formOaram = root;
    while(namespace.length){
        formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
}
    return{
        param : formParam,
        msg   : msg,
        value : value
     };
    }

}));

app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});



app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server is running on port 3000')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a suggestion on the architecture. I would suggest just have the web service calls in express as an api stack. You can then build an angular app that consumes the web services. You can push the angular code into the public folder but I would decouple the UI from the API. You have set up an express js application with jade as the default view engine. You could use that and push angular code in there as well. As long as you include the scripts you should be fine.

Now, for login you would need passportjs - Depending on how you are planning to authenticate you would choose a strategy. For instance, local strategy should be used for authenticating with your own user table. There are other strategies for oauth against FB, Google etc.

For creating a standalone UI app with Angular6 you install the angular/cli and create and run the project. You can consume the REST api calls from this angular project. The login will be one such call.